# Generate multi-page PDF in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, nsdata

I have an array of `UIImage`'s i'd like to make into a long, multi-page PDF with one image per page. I have gotten as far as to make every image in to a PDF represented by NSData, but I'm struggling to find any information on how to combine them into one long document.

My current code looks like this:

```
 //Convert images to pdf
    var pdfDatas = [NSData]()
    for image in images {
        let pdfData = NSData.convertImageToPDF(image)

        pdfDatas.append(pdfData!)


    }
    //Combine PDF's to one long document here.
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

are you using the CoreGraphics PDF functions? If so, I think you can use `CGPDFContextBeginPage()`/`CGPDFContextEndPage()` pairs before and after drawing each page's content.

Something like

```
CGPDFContextCreateWithURL(...)
CGPDFContextBeginPage(...)

// draw image using CGContextDraw functions

CGPDFContextEndPage(...)
```

There's more info in Apple's documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf/dq_pdf.html).

Comment: Yep, thank you. Added a loop for my image array with being and end page.

Answer (score 1):

### Swift 5.5.2, Xcode Version 13.2.1.

Potential solution for an images placed on A4 format (one image per page), centred and keeping their aspect ratios.

Partly got inspired here on [Ray Wenderlich tutorial on working with PDF](https://www.raywenderlich.com/4023941-creating-a-pdf-in-swift-with-pdfkit#toc-anchor-014)

#### Take note of custom code I used in my solution:

`PDFConstants.A4FormatRectangle` is equal to `CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 595, height: 842)`

#### Code you are looking for:

```swift
func getPDFDataFromImages(_ images: [UIImage], page rect: CGRect = PDFConstants.A4FormatRectangle) -> Data {
    
    let maxWidth        = rect.width
    let maxHeight       = rect.height
    
    var pdfData = Data()
    
    for image in images {
        let aspectWidth     = maxWidth / image.size.width
        let aspectHeight    = maxHeight / image.size.height
        let aspectRatio     = min(aspectWidth, aspectHeight)
        
        let scaledWidth     = image.size.width * aspectRatio
        let scaledHeight    = image.size.height * aspectRatio
        
        let imageYPosition  = (maxHeight - scaledHeight) / 2.0 // So it's centred on Y axis
        let imageXPosition  = (maxWidth - scaledWidth) / 2.0 // So it's centred on X axis
        let imageRect       = CGRect(x: imageXPosition, y: imageYPosition, width: scaledWidth, height: scaledHeight)
        
        let renderer = UIGraphicsPDFRenderer(bounds: rect)
        pdfData = renderer.pdfData { context in
            for image in images {
                context.beginPage()
                image.draw(in: imageRect)
            }
        }
    }
    
    return pdfData
}
```

Comment: The documentation of `beginPage()` says "You must call the function endPDFPage()".