# Draw text on all pages of PDF using PDFKit

Tags: swift, macos, pdfkit

I'm using the following code to draw text on a PDF Document.This seems to draw the text only on a single page.I'm trying to iterate through each page,draw string on it and finally display the PDF document from the MutableData. How do I draw the string on all pages?

```
var pdffile=PDFDocument(url: input)
let data = NSMutableData()
let consumer = CGDataConsumer(data: data as CFMutableData)!
for y in stride(from: 0, to: pdffile!.pageCount, by: 1)
{
    let page: PDFPage = pdffile!.page(at: y)!
    let outputBounds = page.bounds(for: PDFDisplayBox.mediaBox)
    var mediaBox = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: outputBounds.size.width, height: outputBounds.size.height)
    let context = CGContext(consumer: consumer, mediaBox: &mediaBox, nil)!
    NSGraphicsContext.current = NSGraphicsContext(cgContext: context, flipped: false)

    context.beginPDFPage(nil)
    page.draw(with: .mediaBox, to: context)
    text.draw(in:drawrect,withAttributes:textFontAttributes);
    context.endPDFPage()
    context.closePDF()
}
let anotherDocument = PDFDocument(data:data as Data)
pdfview.document=anotherDocument
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate multi-page PDF in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35962022/generate-multi-page-pdf-in-swift)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue here is that context recreated, for multiple pages we should write into the same context (it manages pages by beginPDFPage/endPDFPage pair).

Here is fixed code. Tested with Xcode 13.4 / macOS 12.4

```
let pdffile = PDFDocument(url: input)
let data = NSMutableData()
let consumer = CGDataConsumer(data: data as CFMutableData)!

// create common context with no mediaBox, we will add it later
// per-page (because, actually they might be different)
let context = CGContext(consumer: consumer, mediaBox: nil, nil)!

for y in stride(from: 0, to: pdffile!.pageCount, by: 1)
{
    let page: PDFPage = pdffile!.page(at: y)!

    // re-use media box of original document as-is w/o changes !!
    var mediaBox = page.bounds(for: PDFDisplayBox.mediaBox)
    NSGraphicsContext.current = NSGraphicsContext(cgContext: context, flipped: false)

    // prepare mediaBox data for page setup
    let rectData = NSData(bytes: &mediaBox, length: MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: mediaBox))

    context.beginPDFPage([kCGPDFContextMediaBox as String: rectData] as CFDictionary)   // << here !!

    page.draw(with: .mediaBox, to: context) // << original !!
    text.draw(in:drawrect,withAttributes:textFontAttributes) // << over !!

    context.endPDFPage()
}
context.closePDF()  // close entire document

let anotherDocument = PDFDocument(data:data as Data)
// ... as used before
```

Comment: This is great but where do you save the document.  I expected to see it converted to nsdata and saved